# How to fix 'need at least one array to concatenate' error?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have read through the various posts on ValueError but I'm not getting much satisfactory solution. Please, can anyone help me what I am doing wrong??

Code:

```
 assert(type(images) == list)
 # assert(type(images[0]) == np.ndarray)
 # assert(len(images[0].shape) == 3)
 # assert(np.max(images[0]) > 10)
 # assert(np.min(images[0]) >= 0.0)
 inps = []
 for img in images:
   img = img.astype(np.float32)
   inps.append(np.expand_dims(img, 0))
 bs = 100
 with tf.Session() as sess:
   preds = []
   n_batches = int(math.ceil(float(len(inps)) / float(bs)))
   for i in range(n_batches):
       sys.stdout.write(".")
       sys.stdout.flush()
       inp = inps[(i * bs):min((i + 1) * bs, len(inps))]
       inp = np.concatenate(inp, 0)
       pred = sess.run(softmax, {'ExpandDims:0': inp})
       preds.append(pred)
   preds = np.concatenate(preds, 0)
   scores = []
   for i in range(splits):
     part = preds[(i * preds.shape[0] // splits):((i + 1) * preds.shape[0] // splits), :]
     kl = part * (np.log(part) - np.log(np.expand_dims(np.mean(part, 0), 0)))
     kl = np.mean(np.sum(kl, 1))
     scores.append(np.exp(kl))
   return np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)
```

> Error :

```
>File "/content/Inception-Score/inception_score.py", line 45, in >get_inception_score
>    preds = np.concatenate(preds, 0)
>ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are missing the argument for the array you would like to concatenate. You specified the initial array and the axis to concatenate on, but not the second array -- hence "need at least one array to concatenate".

np.concatenate() has a minimum of two arrays in the first argument, as detailed in the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). Looks like "preds" is only one array. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but maybe concatenate is not what you want?

Comment: I understand what you mean to say. But inp = np.concatenate(inp, 0) this is working. Here aslo a single array is passed

Comment: Can you confirm that the first loop is ever running? I am wondering if `n_batches` has ever been greater than 0, because if it were greater than 0 that too should generate an error.

Comment: You're right @Cade. Even the first loop was not running.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in `np.concatenate` where it expects an array of arrays and you are not providing that

```
#syntax
numpy.concatenate((a1, a2, ...), axis=0, out=None)
```

> Parameters:
>   a1, a2, … : sequence of array_like The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).
>
> axis : int, optional The axis along which the arrays will be joined. If axis is None, arrays are flattened before use. Default is 0.
>
> out : ndarray, optional If provided, the destination to place the result. The shape must be correct, matching that of what concatenate would have returned if no out argument were specified.
>
> Returns: ndarray The concatenated array.

check `preds` what it returns

Comment: I understand what you mean to say. But `inp = np.concatenate(inp, 0)` this is working. Here aslo a single array is passed.